# Twitter in ruby on rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter, rubygems, helper

I want to include my tweets on my homepage. Currently I have a helper which looks like this:

```
module WelcomesHelper

 def recent_tweets(user)
   html = "<div>"
   Twitter.user_timeline(user).each do |tweet|
       html << '<span class="tweet">' << tweet.text << '</span>'
   end 
   html << "</div>"
 end
```

end

However, it can not find the twitter gem. If it require it from irb it works fine, but how do I include it in my rails app?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rails3 - add

```
gem 'Twitter'
```

to your Gemfile, run bundle and it should work in your application.